# How to append input values to a html table using forEach method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, foreach, html-table

I want to get input values from all the input fields using forEach and want to return an object and send to the table to display. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<form>
      <input name="date" value="date" type="date" placeholder="date" />
      <input name="item" value="item" type="text" placeholder="item name" />
      <input name="qty" value="qty" type="text" placeholder="quantity" />
      <input name="amt" value="amt" type="text" placeholder="price" />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th width="10%">Sr.No.</th>
          <th width="10%">Date</th>
          <th width="60%">Name</th>
          <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
          <th width="10%">Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="datafield">
          <!-- <td>1</td>
          <td>1.1.2022</td>
          <td>pencil</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>45</td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" align="right"><b>TOTAL</b></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**
This is the javascript code I have written. I don't understand how to append html.

```
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input")];
      const button = document.querySelector("button");
      const datafield = document.querySelector(".datafield");

      button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let datafield = {};
        let x = [];
        inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
          x.push(input.value);
        });
        datafield.innerHTML = `<td>1</td>
          <td>1.1.2022</td>
          <td>pencil</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>45</td>`;
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way. Check the updated code below.

**HTML**

```
<form>
      <input name="sr.no" value="1" type="number" placeholder="sr.no" />
      <input name="date" value="date" type="date" placeholder="date" />
      <input name="item" value="item" type="text" placeholder="item name" />
      <input name="qty" value="qty" type="text" placeholder="quantity" />
      <input name="amt" value="amt" type="text" placeholder="price" />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th width="10%">Sr.No.</th>
          <th width="10%">Date</th>
          <th width="60%">Name</th>
          <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
          <th width="10%">Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="datafield"></tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" align="right"><b>TOTAL</b></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");
  const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input")];
  const datafield = document.querySelector(".datafield");

  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
      const td = document.createElement("td");
      tr.appendChild(td);
      const values = document.createTextNode(input.value);
      td.appendChild(values);
      console.log(td);
      datafield.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", tr);
      input.value = "";
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is your assigning data field twice. So when you set innerHTML of datafield your actually calling that on the variable that's defined inside the event listener which isn't the variable that contains the DOM element.

Try:

```
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')];
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const datafield = document.querySelector('.datafield');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let x = [];
  inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
    x.push(input.value);
  });

  datafield.innerHTML += x.map((item) => `<td>${item}</td>`).join('');
});
```

Comment: tr.forEach((td) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
            const td = document.createElement("td");
            const text = document.createTextNode(input.value);
            td.appendChild(text);
            datafield.innerHTML = td;
          });
        });
      }); //I did by doing something like this but how to display?

Comment: these are variables - const button = document.querySelector("button");
      const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input")];
      const tr = [...document.querySelectorAll(".datafield")];
      const datafield = document.querySelector(".datafield");

Comment: now it's working but I don't know how to display?

Comment: Can you ad an updated snippet of your code, but leave the original aswell.

Comment: Hey thanks @Obsidianlab. I found the way and this worked for me and I added the answer. Please check and comment as well.

Comment: If it works for you its fine! :D Dont forget to upvote and accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Hey really thank you for your efforts but I didn't find your answer helpful. I wanted to append the row whenever I get values from the input.

Comment: All you change in my code to do that is the following `datafield.innerHTML += x.map((item) => \`<td>${item}</td>\`).join(''); `That means changing the = to a += this is basic JS knownledge. Next time please ask your question better that you want to append a row and not just add the data cuz that is very different. You have to be very specific when you ask your questions. I also updated the answer.